# Domination number and induced chromatic number

Tags: graph-domination

Graph theory is not really my field and hopefully I am not asking something silly.
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph (say connected and regular because it is the case I am interested in, but I am curious also in general).

I am interested in the chromatic number of the subgraph induced by $G$ on a domination set of smallest possible cardinality $\gamma(G)$.
Is there any general information on this number or is there some hope to obtain some information using the vertex degree?